# Splitting String Array, then using each element separately

Tags: c#, arrays, string, usb

I'm trying to split an array, which gets its data from a list string. I've managed to split the string, but I can't seem to work out how to use each element of the split string separately. Here's what I have:

```
        DriveInfo[] loadedDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo ld in loadedDrives)
        {
            if (ld.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
            {
                if (ld.IsReady == true)
                {             
                        deviceInfo.Add(ld.VolumeLabel + ": , " + ld.TotalSize + ": , " + ld.AvailableFreeSpace + ": , " + ld.DriveFormat);        //Add data to list      
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (String st in deviceInfo)
        {

            string[] deviceSel;

            deviceSel = st.Split(splitChar);
            string toDisplay = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, deviceSel);
            MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);

        }
```

Now the output I get from this is something like:

- USB Device Name
- Total Storage Size
- Total Free Space
- Type of Drive Format

These change depending on the USB in question. Is there a way that I can get each one of those points in separate variables, or is there a better way to what I have done?

Comment: Wait, you already have it! Right before you join it back with newline, you've got each string in a separate array element. `deviceSel[0]` is your `"USB Device Name"`, `deviceSel[1]` is `"Total Storage Size"`, and so on. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight, that worked perfectly! However, when i have 2 USB devices working, the program lists both their information when I use your suggestion. Any way of working around this?

Comment: I'm sure you get the two sets of infos separately - one on each iteration of the loop, in the same way your current program shows multiple message boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work:

```
deviceSel = st.Split(splitChar);
string toDisplay = "";
foreach (string device in deviceSel)
{
    toDisplay += device + Environment.NewLine;

}
MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);
```

You can either do it in a loop or access based on index as @dasblinkenlight suggested.